# How to fix MacBook showing Android hostname in Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I use terminal quite often, for some reason all of a sudden Terminal is showing a strange `android-1e1c8882e08308f9` hostname (see image) in the prompt.

I've checked my MacBook's hostname in Sharing Preferences and this is correct, but Terminal is still showing the android hostname.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Comment: You may be getting a different host name from your DHCP server.

Comment: You may be right, I'm using a public WiFi connection at the moment. I'll see if it fixes itself when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: What does the `hostname` command show you?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal and http://superuser.com/questions/357159/osx-terminal-showing-incorrect-hostname

Comment: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10362633-263.html suggests editing `/etc/hostconfig` to add `HOSTNAME=yourhostname` at the end.

Answer (score 12):

By default, the host name of your computer is not set. The Sharing panel lets you set the computer name, which is a Mac OS X-specific attribute. My theory is that if the host name is not set, `hostname` (and your shell prompt) will use this value instead. The following is the output of `scutil` and `hostname` on my laptop.

```
patikoija ~ % scutil --get ComputerName
patikoija
patikoija ~ % scutil --get LocalHostName
patikoija
patikoija ~ % scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
patikoija ~ % hostname
patikoija.local
```

When I visit my company's office, my host name is similarly set to something that begins with 'dhcp-'. I suppose that the DHCP server sets the actual host name, and running `scutil` there would show that name. You can try using `scutil` to set the true host name of your computer, and see if that "resists" efforts by the DHCP server to override it.

Comment: `scutil --set HostName [NewHostName]`